# Firestore update from 1.0 to 2.0 breaks database model

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've posted my database model and then the code below where the map is called. The following line >>>
`MarkerCollectModel model = MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(map()!)`
gives me an error of error: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I've been reading over the migration changes [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/) but can seem to make sense of them.

How do I make the model work with the new version of firestore?

```
class MarkerCollectModel {
  double? lat, lng;
  String? name, detail,  dateTime, uid;

  MarkerCollectModel(
      {this.lat,
        this.lng,
        this.name,
        this.detail,
        this.dateTime,
        this.uid});

  MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    lat = map['Lat'];
    lng = map['Lng'];
    name = map['Speed'];
    detail = map['Racer'];
    dateTime = map['DateTime'];
    uid = map['Uid'];
  }
}



Future<void> readDataFromFirebase() async {
    print('###############readDataFromFirebase Work####################');
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
    firestore.collection('usertest');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = event.docs;
      for (var map in snapshots) {
        MarkerCollectModel model = MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(map()!);
        String nameDocument = map.id;
        listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
        print('Name ==>> ${model.name}');
        Marker marker = createMarker(model, nameDocument);
        setState(() {
          list.add(marker);
          print('myMarkers set lenght ==>> ${myMarkers().length}');
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) you should do something like that:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

So, in your case would be:

```
for (var map in snapshots) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = map!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // add this line
    MarkerCollectModel model = MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(data); // use data here
    String nameDocument = map.id;
    listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
    print('Name ==>> ${model.name}');
    Marker marker = createMarker(model, nameDocument);
    setState(() {
       list.add(marker);
       print('myMarkers set lenght ==>> ${myMarkers().length}');
    });
}
```